# Showing a function is convex on $x^2+y^2\leq a^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

This is a question from my assignment about which I have no idea:
Let $f(x,y)=\phi(x^2+y^2)$,where $\phi$ is of class $C^2$ ,increasing and concave.

Show that $f$ is convex on disk $x^2+y^2\leq a^2$ if and only if $\phi'(u)+2u\phi''(u)\geq 0$ whenever $0\leq u\leq a^2.$

Can anyone please help me with this....

Comment: where do you have problems? Start with the definition of convexity for $f$.. where does that takes you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning: It has been pointed out to me that the proof is flawed as convexity over $r$ does not necessarily imply convexity over $(x,y)$. Any suggestions as to how to repair it are greatly appreciated.

You can write this in polar coordinates

\begin{align*}
f(x,y) \rightarrow f(r) = \phi(r^2)
\end{align*}

A twice differentiable function (of one variable) is convex if and only if $\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}r^2} f(r) \geq 0$ on the entire domain. We have

\begin{align*}
&\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} r} f(r) = 2r \phi'(r^2) \\
& \frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}r^2} f(r) = 2 \phi'(r^2) + 4r^2 \phi''(r^2)
\end{align*}

Now, $2 \phi'(r^2) + 4r \phi''(r^2) \geq 0 \implies \phi'(r^2) + 2r^2 \phi''(r^2) \geq 0$. Now introduce $u = r^2$. The condition reduces to

\begin{align*}
\phi'(u) + 2u \phi''(u) \geq 0
\end{align*}

As $\phi$ is increasing, we have $\phi' \geq 0$ but as $\phi$ is concave, too, we have $\phi'' \leq 0$, therefore, this condition has to hold and depends on the properties of $\phi$.

Comment: and why is "A twice differentiable function (of one variable) is convex if and only if d^2/dr^2 f(r)≥0 "?

Comment: because then $f'(r)$ is monotonically non-decreasing, i.e. the derivative only increases (or stays constant). Draw such a function and you shall see that it is indeed convex. Alternatively you may google for this very well known proof.

Comment: I get that. My question is how to pass from convex as a function of the variable $r$ to convex as a function of $(x,y)$.

Comment: You're right, this proof is flawed, any suggestions as to how to repair it ?

Comment: well, check my answer. Too bad this one has been accepted.

Comment: I didn't upvote it

Comment: sure, as it is your answer ;) start with an upvote of mine :p

Comment: there you go :-)

Comment: that is nice! now the problem is that the accepted answer is not good. Maybe you can start with an edit of your post. I don't know if there is a patch to fix the problem and still use your method.

Comment: How should I edit my post if I don't know how to correct it ?

Comment: Just add a warning at the top of it, saying that the answer is not quite right at the moment, so that anyone who read it later does not make the same mistake.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Consider $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$ such as $$
x_1^2 + y_1^2\le a^2\\
x_2^2 + y_2^2\le a^2
$$
Consider $g:[0,1]\to \Bbb R$, $g(t) = f(t (x_1,y_1) + (1-t) (x_2,y_2))$.

$f$ is convex iff for every choice of $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_2)$ the function $g$ is convex.